# Unable to locate Android SDK in settings menu of android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I'm unable to locate Android SDK in the settings menu of android studio

Today, when I run Android Studio, I saw a problem with it. I can't see "android_SDK", in setting menu. not exist in left menu "setting>system setting". What happened??? can you help me to solve it. I reinstalled android studio but problem not solved. In my C drive I can see SDK in default directory but in android studio not exist.

[image: android sdk not exist in setting menu]

in below image you can see my configuration.
[image: sdk configuration]

in below you can see plugin info
[image: plugin property]

[image: sdk manager _ all package installed]

Comment: just search `SDK` in the searchBox there..

Comment: check your plugin. Probably your android plugin is disabled.

Comment: Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager

Comment: sdk manager (see last image ) all installed

Comment: thanks for your attention. I found this problem , I cleaed android log files from below location. then Problem solved.:)

C:\Users\user_pc\.AndroidStudio2.2\system\log

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> Other Settings -> Default Project Structure tab.

you will probably find SDK LOCATION here...

Make Sure View -> Toolbar is checked.

Answer (score 0):

you must update SDK tools first